# Extending inherited nested subclasses in c#

Tags: c#, inheritance, asp.net-web-api, subclass, nested-class

I have a situation where we have a class with a number of deeply nested subclasses used to generate an XML/Json export for a webapi. The top level class calls the constructor of each nested class to generate the populated object and then it's passed to the webapi to serialize. In reality there is a lot of processing goes on as the domain model and the export format is very different to the domain model but I've produced a highly simplified example below.

We now have a requirement for a new export which mimics the original but contains some additional data. That seems like something I ought to be able to solve with inheritance or partial classes, but I can't figure out how.

```
//EF Domain Model Classes
public class Product
{
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public List<Colour> Colours { get; set; } 
}

public class Colour {
    public string ColourName { get; set; }
}

//Highly simplified classes for generating exportable 
public class ExportProuducts
{
    public class ExportProduct
    {
        public List<ExportProductColour> ExportColours { get; set; }
        public string exportsku { get; set; }

        public ExportProduct() { }
        public ExportProduct(Product prod)
        {
            exportsku = prod.Sku;
            ExportColours = new List<ExportProductColour>();
            foreach (var colour in prod.Colours)
            {
                ExportColours.Add(new ExportProductColour(colour));
            }
        }

        public class ExportProductColour
        {
            string ExportColourName { get; set; }

            public ExportProductColour() { }
            public ExportProductColour(Colour colour)
            {
                ExportColourName = colour.ColourName;
            }
        }
    }

}

public class SomeNewRequirement : ExportProuducts
{
    //This isn't going to work because nothing initializes it
    public class ExportProductColourNewRequirement : ExportProduct.ExportProductColour
    {
        public string ExportColourShade { get; set; }

        public ExportProductColourNewRequirement(){}
        public ExportProductColourNewRequirement(Colour colour) : base(colour)
        {
            ExportColourShade = GetShade(colour);
        }

    }
}
```

What I'm really trying to achieve is to add some new properties and initialize them into one of the classes nested 3 or 4 deep. Is this even possible. I've got control of the ExportProduct class so can make any changes required there.

Comment: It's not clear *why* you're nesting at all here, but it seems irrelevant to the problem. Basically, you need the code which is deserializing the `ExportProductColour` to sometimes create an instance of `ExportProductColourNewRequirement` instead. I don't have any experience of Web API - but you should look at whether/how it lets you control deserialization. I would start by taking a *much* simpler example though.

Comment: the nesting is probably not important - it seemed like a "natural" way to do it given the shape of the output but I think it could be flattened without too much issue.

Comment: ignoring the webapi part for now, are you implying that there isn't a way I can inherit from ExportProducts and add a property "deeper" in  - even if I flatten the structures out? If not I'll look at your approach to attack it at the serialization level.

Comment: Well the fact that `SomeNewRequirement` derives from `ExportProducts` is entirely irrelevant to the fact that `ExportProductColourNewRequirement` derives from `ExportProduct.ExportProductColour`. Again, I think the nesting is adding confusion here. You can certainly derive from `ExportProduct.ExportProductColour`, but you'd need to persuade the deserialization code to create instances of that instead of the base class.

Comment: I'm just beginning to understand the irrelevance you describe. However, its not being deserialzied - its being serialized by the exporter, so that approach is not going to help either: its all over with before the serializer gets involved. I wonder if I can do anything in the code that new's up the ExportProducts (in the base class) to new up an instance of one or the other.

Comment: Okay, if the serializer isn't involved, and so it's *all* your own code, that makes life a lot simpler. So how would you expect your `ExportProduct` constructor to know whether to create an `ExportProductColour` or an `ExportProductColourNewRequirement`?

Comment: Initial reaction is whether it was a typeof "SomeNewRequirement" but that involves the nested class knowing about the outer ones (which I don't think it does). Another red herring. I guess I can throw a bool extended flag into the mix and pass it around as appropriate.